# Reading and writing from the console in js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I've a simple problem from Hacker Rank.

There are N strings. Each string's length is no more than 20 characters. There are also Q queries. For each query, you are given a string, and you need to find out how many times this string occurred previously. The first line contains , the number of strings. The next N lines each contain a string. The N + 2nd line contains , the number of queries.
The following Q lines each contain a query string.

Sample Input

```
4
aba
baba
aba
xzxb
3
aba
xzxb
ab
```

Sample Output

```
2
1
0
```

Here's the provided code,

```
function processData(input) {
    //Enter your code here


} 

process.stdin.resume();
process.stdin.setEncoding("ascii");
_input = "";

process.stdin.on("data", function (input) {

    _input += input;
});

process.stdin.on("end", function () {
   processData(_input);
});
```

The solution to the problem is simple.
Initialize a hashmap. Enter the values in the N strings in the hashmap against occurence count.

```
var map = {};
  if(!map[input])map[input]++;
  else map[input] = 1;
```

And then for each query return the get on the respective key.

The issue is I'm new to javascript and have no clue about node. Can someone help me understand the code and help me in figuring out the scopes in which the respective data structures will have to instantiated.

Comment: I think that your if statement need to be swapped, `if (!map[input]) { map[input] = 1; } else { map[input]++; }`

Answer (score 0):

You need to put your code in :

```
function processData(input) {
// split your input and access it

//your logic
 var map = {};
  if(!map[input])map[input]=1;
  else map[input] +=1;

//your output
console.log('...');
}
```

**Explaination**

Start reading from stdin so we don't exit.

```
process.stdin.resume();
```

Reads the input data

```
process.stdin.on("data", function (input) {

    _input += input;
});
```

On completion of data calls the end event is fired.

```
process.stdin.on("end", function () {
   processData(_input);
});
```